# Where to practice creating a post (for *stackoverflow)

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

first post here:

stackoverflow posts can be very complex (using formatting code and other elements).

## hash appears to make heading... where is comment?

//sample code (java, android); let's see how this looks

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    mListener = (MPQGenDialogListener) getTargetFragment();
    if (null == mListener) {
        mListener = (MPQGenDialogListener) activity;
    }
    if (null == mListener) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement MPQGenDialogListener");
    }
} // END onAttach()
```

Where can one practice creating (and/or answering) *stackoverflow questions?
[In effect I am attempting to answer that in this question, but I may get stricken down or a better method may be identified].

A "helloworld" tag would be nice/appropriate :-D .

Comment: What's wrong with the preview that appears below the textarea as you're typing?

Comment: @animuson preview is ok, but it's not the full "post" experience (such as this interaction).  Thx for feedback.

Comment: i disagree with the duplicate closure -- my query was not only per a formatting sandbox, but per a stackoverflow sandbox.  thx regardless.

Answer (score 6):

If the question/answer preview doesn't do it for you (it shows up below the input textbox), you can also use the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: thx - the Formatting Sandbox is definitely interesting (and intimidating).  I was looking more for the experience I got out of this post however.

Comment: @donfede So if we downvote your question and then close it, that'll be more valuable experience? Anything to help...

Comment: @itsbruce You're welcome to :) -- personally I think there is value in a sandbox environment (potentially without 'karma') to go through the experience.  This run-through has been enough to get me to post a Q and answer a couple Q on "main".